# How to fetch values from MySQL from Chrome App using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome app and want to fetch values from MySQL DB. I looked around and could not find any clear reference material.

I am trying to connect my Chrome app with MySQL db and not sure how to do this.

Web app code:

JS

```
function FrmController($scope, $http) {
//$scope.errors = [];
//$scope.msgs = [];
$scope.AddTask = function() {
//$scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
//$scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length); 
$http.post('https://example-sb.appspot.com/create_task.php', {'mytask': $scope.mytask, done:false}
    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log($scope.mytask);
        $scope.mytask = "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way you can create an intermediary web app that will interface with the Database. Then you can make AJAX calls from your Chrome app to your web app's API, which will in turn query the database and return results.

Chrome App → Web App API → MySQL

[Reference about Chrome AJAX API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. I already have a working web app. Did you mean I use that? Also should I build my own API?

Comment: @krish_cloudnow, gui47 means that you should use a server side app, a webApi. If you already have a server side app, it looks like you have a PHP app -- you can use that. The best practice would be to follow a common recognizable pattern. Probably use Rest. There are frameworks to do most of this for you -- or you can hand code this.

Comment: Thank you gui47 and Martin I will start looking more into it and read about it.